# iOS how to build ffmpeg

Tags: objective-c, ios, ffmpeg

How to build ffmpeg for iOS? I have got 5.0 framework and scripts from iFrameExtractor fail to build it with - invalid operand on inline asm ldr ${0:q}, $1

Do you have a successfull experience with it?

Answer (score 0):

I created a project at https://github.com/ciphor/ffmpeg4ios, which is base on ffmpeg-0.7, and iOS 5.0 SDK.